# swipe-down event not firing - ionic framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a simple app with the ionic framework, and I want to run a function on each of the swipe events. Swipe Up, down, left, and right.

```
    <ion-content on-swipe-up="add()" on-swipe-left="multiply()" on-swipe-right="divide()" on-swipe-down="subtract()" scroll="false">
    <div id="game">
        <h1>{{subject.value}}</h1> 
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

All of the events work fine, except on-swipe-down. No matter what I do, I cannot get that event to fire. I have tried everything I can think of: setting the scroll property, attaching the events to different elements, emulating instead of in the browser, and have made a new bare-bones project where I'm just testing the on-swipe-down event. Nothing has worked.

[**CorePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/enwtb)

Comment: Sorry, Here is the Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/enwtb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is a bug.

I filed a Github issue. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1810

In the meantime, if you use a local copy of the bundle.js file, make the following change:

Line 40918, change:

```
'onHold onTap onTouch onRelease onDrag onDragUp onDragRight onDragDown onDragLeft onSwipe onSwipeUp onSwipeRight onSwipeBottom onSwipeLeft'.split(' '),
```

to

```
'onHold onTap onTouch onRelease onDrag onDragUp onDragRight onDragDown onDragLeft onSwipe onSwipeUp onSwipeRight onSwipeDown onSwipeLeft'.split(' '),
```

Comment: Thank you!! Works perfectly now. Will need to keep in mind to look at the source more carefully when something like this happens.